# scrapy rule extractor is not working with proxy

Tags: python, proxy, web-scraping, scrapy, http-proxy

My rule for link extractor is like this, which is for pagination

```
rules = (
        Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_xpaths=('//a[@class="button next"]',)), callback="parse_items", follow= True),
    )
```

And I am yielding a request here

```
def start_requests(self):
        CrawlSpider.start_requests(self)  
        in_url = self.base_url + "Ahmedabad"
        print "******************req_url********************",in_url
        req = Request(in_url, dont_filter=True)
        req.meta['proxy']="http://52.71.9.25:8080"
        yield req
```

But rule extractor is not iterating if I use proxy and if I remove `req.meta['proxy']="http://52.71.9.25:8080"` it is working fine.

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: edit the question with your `settings.py` file

Comment: is it working if you just remove the `req.meta['proxy'] ...` line?

Comment: @eLRuLL yep it's working

Comment: then maybe it is the site working differently for a proxy (maybe the site checks region, or it has even detected the proxy), try doing single requests to check the response status and body.